# Add appointment on JQuery FullCalendar with double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, double-click

I'm fiddling around with JQuery Full Calendar and what I'd like to figure out with your help is adding an event to the calendar by Double Clicking. I wired up the double click event in the JQuery, however I am not exactly sure what to do with it. When I double click the calendar, it does display a popup window which is fine. I know how to send an event's details to the code behind. I guess my big issue is when the person double clicks, how do I bring up a form for them to fill out? I only have four fields and the all-day option to pass into Exchange via EWS. That side works just fine. So I need help figuring out how to do two things.

1. When they double click, bring up a form for them to add details
2. Send the information to the code behind - re-use the ajax call? Create a new one?

   ```
       $(document).ready(function () {
       initThemeChooser({
           init: function (themeSystem) {
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                   themeSystem: themeSystem,
                   header: {
                       left: 'prev,next today',
                       center: 'title',
                       right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
                   },
                   selectable: true,
                   selectHelper: true,
                   weekNumbers: true,
                   navLinks: true,
                   editable: true,
                   eventLimit: true,
                   events:  <% =JsonEvent %>,
                   eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
                       if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?"))     {
                           revertFunc();
                       } else {
                           UpdateEvent(event);
                           $(this).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                       }
                   },
                   eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                       alert(event.title + " changed end is now " + event.end.format());
                       if (!confirm("is this okay?")) {
                           revertFunc();
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           UpdateEvent(event);
                           $(this).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                       }
                   },
                   eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                       alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title + '\nDate: ' + moment(calEvent.Start).format("MM-DD-YYYY") + '\nStart: ' + moment(calEvent.start).format("hh:mm:ss A") + '\nEnd: ' + moment(calEvent.end).format("hh:mm:ss A"));
                       $(this).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                       // change the border color just for fun
                       $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

                   },
                   eventDoubleClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                       alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
                       alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
                       alert('View: ' + view.name);

                       // change the border color just for fun
                       $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                   }
               });

               function UpdateEvent(event)
               {
                   var data = {};
                   data.id = event.id;
                   data.starts = event.start;
                   data.ends = event.end;
                   data.subject = event.title;

                   $.ajax({
                       url: 'Calendar.aspx/UpdateEvent',
                       method: 'POST',
                       dataType: 'JSON',
                       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                       data: JSON.stringify(data),
                       success: function (response, type, xhr) {
                           var retVal = JSON.stringify(response);
                       },
                       error: function (xhr) {
                           window.alert('error: ' + xhr.statusText);
                       }

                   });

               }
           },
           change: function (themeSystem) {
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'themeSystem', themeSystem);
           }

       });
   });
   ```

Comment: 1) instead of the alerts, display a new div (maybe using CSS styling etc to make it effectively a modal dialog) containing your form. 2) I assume that Create needs to behave slightly differently to Update so I guess you'd need a slightly different ajax call as well.

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: ADyson, post your comment as an answer, I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the approach you should take:

1) instead of the alerts, display a new div (maybe using CSS styling etc to make it effectively a modal dialog) containing your form.

2) I assume that Create needs to behave slightly differently to Update so I guess you'd need a slightly different ajax call as well.